# How to use serviceProvider into other file laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.8

I´m traying to use my new serviceProvider into `mail.php` because i need get values from database not `.env` i can show one solution in this site that one person creaed a serviceProvider and get all data that he needed.

My question is, how i can use this provider into mail.php?

**my provider:**

```
public function register()
{
    if (\Schema::hasTable('app_settings')) {
        $mail = DB::table('app_settings')->first();
        if ($mail) //checking if table is not empty
        {
            $config = array(
                'driver'     => $mail->driver,
                'host'       => $mail->host,
                'port'       => $mail->port,
                'from'       => array('address' => $mail->from_address, 'name' => $mail->from_name),
                'encryption' => $mail->encryption,
                'username'   => $mail->username,
                'password'   => $mail->password,
                'sendmail'   => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
                'pretend'    => false,
            );
            Config::set('mail', $config);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Bootstrap services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    //
}
```

**mail.php**

for example: `'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),`

how i can call driver of provider into driver mail.php

thanks for help, rewards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it, and it's not a good idea.

The simplest way is to override your config after everything was loaded.

You can use your `AppServiceProdiver.php` file, and in the `boot()` function :

```
public function boot()
{
   // adapt of course...
   $yourConfig = \DB::select('SELECT * FROM your_config_table');

   config()->set([
       'app.mail.driver' => $yourConfig[0]->value
   ]);
}
```

Comment: @VicentDecaux thanks for your response, but i don´t have a model with this information. I have this information in DB

Comment: Just run the query you need, I can't help you more here